# how to make an image show when radio button is clicked

Tags: android-studio, radio-button

I know this is a simple question but I'm a beginner and I have this homework where we
have to make an image show when the radio button is clicked but they didn't teach us anything about that
because of coronavirus so I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me how to do it.

Comment: What programming language/framework are you working on? What did you try so far? Add some code here.

Answer (score 0):

For creating two radio buttons with simple image, and control visibility of image when check one of the radio buttons, I will give some simple steps to build that in `java`.

After build a new empty activity project:

1. You can open the wanted files from project explorer as shown :
   [image: project explorer]
2. go to `activity_main.xml` which is the layout file, I will create Linear layout with image and radio group contains two radio buttons,and I used imageview `android:src` attribute as a color (you can change it to image):

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:text="Hello World!"
       android:visibility="gone" />

   <RadioGroup
       android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="16dp"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/radio_button_choice1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="choice-1" />

       <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/radio_button_choice2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="choice-2" />

   </RadioGroup>
   ```
3. Second, we need to go to java file named as `MainActivity` which is java file, and we will get the views and create a listener on the `RadioGroup` which we will use to show and hide the image (some comments help you understands the java code):

   ```
   package com.your.packagename.here;

   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.RadioGroup;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private ImageView image;
   private RadioGroup radioGroup;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       //intit views
       image = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

       //create the listener for radio group
       radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
               //check if the choice-1 is selected
               if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio_button_choice1) {
                   //show image wen select choice-1
                   image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               } else {
                   //hide image when choice-1 not selected
                   image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }
           }
       });

   }
   }
   ```

Finally, and you will get similar to this.

[image: result]

I hope this was helped you.